# Windows 2003 registry setting DST

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003-r2, windows-registry

On Windows 7, you can use this key to enable/disable DST settings in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation Value Name: DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled Value Type: REG_DWORD

I am looking specifically for Windows 2003 DST settings in the registry. Basically I want to "enable" DST settings on a a large group of computers through the registry. Let me know if you guys know where this key is located.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

A key in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` named `DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet`.  It's a `REG_DWORD` type with a value of `0x1` [hex] or `1` [decimal].  If present, your computer clock will **not** update with DST.

If that key is absent, it means your computer will update its clock with Daylight Savings.  So, you'd basically be looking to find that key (and remove it, if present) for your large number of servers.